# How to put a jar in classpath in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant

Hi I am n00b in classpath and Ant. While reading the tutorial of GCM for Android I came across a line

**Step 1: Copy the gcm.jar file into your application classpath**

> To write your Android application, first copy the gcm.jar file from
>   the SDK's gcm-client/dist directory to your application classpath.

I got the gcm.jar from the `dist` folder. Now how do I put it into my classpath using Eclipse(I think that would be easier)? And where would I make changes if I didnt have Eclipse?

Thnaks

Comment: where i can get the gcm.jar file ??

Comment: its in the sample project for GCM..

Comment: Thanks, Your asking my exact quandary. I am also implementing GCM Service for android and didn't know where the lib goes. Gotta love SO :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As of rev 17 of the Android Developer Tools, the correct way to add a library jar when.using the tools and Eclipse is to create a directory called `libs` on the same level as your `src` and `assets` directories and then drop the jar in there.  Nothing else.required, the tools take care of all the rest for you automatically.

Comment: ya i know this, this is correct way to add jar file to the project.

Comment: Hi Barak, just wondering what is the advantage of doing it this way rather than `right click project > Properties > java Build Path > Add External JARs...`

Answer (score 35):

**Right click** on the project in which you want to put jar file. A window will open like this

[image]

Click on the **AddExternal Jars** there you can give the path to that jar file

Comment: @sai:
From the SDK Manager:
install Extras > Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library.

Note: If you don't see Extras > Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library in the SDK Manager, make sure you are running version 20 or higher. Be sure to restart the SDK Manager after updating it.

Answer (score 6):

First copy your jar file and paste into you Android project's libs folder.

Now right click on newly added (Pasted) jar file and select option

> Build Path -> Add to build path

Now you added jar file will get displayed under **Referenced Libraries**. Again right click on it and select option

> Build Path -> Configure Build path

A new window will get appeared.
Select **Java Build Path** from left menu panel and then select **Order and export**
Enable check on added jar file.

Now run your project.

More details @ 
[Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

Right click your project in eclipse, build path -> add external jars.

Comment: Not for.android with r17+ of the developer tools.

Comment: @Barak Oh, sorry I didn't realize that it was different.

Answer (score 1):

In your Android Developer Tools , From the SDK Manager, install Extras > Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library . After the installation is complete restart your SDK.Then navigate to sdk\extras\google\gcm\gcm-client\dist .
there will be your gcm.jar file.