# Exception thrown while running JUnit tests using maven

Tags: junit4, jmockit

I got the following exception while running JUnit tests in Maven.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Native library for Attach API not available in this JRE
    at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(JDK6AgentLoader.java:81)
    at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.loadAgent(JDK6AgentLoader.java:54)
    at mockit.internal.startup.AgentInitialization.initializeAccordingToJDKVersion(AgentInitialization.java:21)
    at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initializeIfNeeded(Startup.java:96)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.JMockit.<clinit>(JMockit.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.<init>(JUnit4TestSet.java:45)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.createTestSet(JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.locateTestSets(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.getTestSets(SurefireBooter.java:455)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesForkPerTestSet(SurefireBooter.java:406)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.run(SurefireBooter.java:249)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.execute(SurefirePlugin.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\attach.dll already loaded in another classloader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1772)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1724)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.<clinit>(WindowsVirtualMachine.java:169)
    at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(JDK6AgentLoader.java:68)
    ... 44 more
```

I have used mocking in my tests.The framework used is JMockit. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this duplicate loading of "attach.dll" occurs (will investigate later), but you can avoid the problem by using the "`-javaagent`" JVM initialization parameter. See [here](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/RunningTests.html#maven) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a try. Here it says something like:

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\attach.dll already loaded in another classloader

My guess is that you try to load the dll twice? Once maybe it's loaded as a maven dependency and once as from the jdk?

Comment: Ok...if the guess is true, then how I can prevent twice loading?

Comment: @SnehaParameswaran you could try to delete the dll from the jdk and leave the one from maven. As far as I know, even if you would find where the dependency of the dll is in maven, it will be verh hard to ignore it from there. You could just the delete the dll from the jdk and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding tools.jar to your classpath. If you've downloaded a JDK, it is typically in Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar under your JDK root. If you're using Eclipse, [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11463590/591374) on another question.