# Very basic thing about ELKI

Tags: java, data-mining, elki

In fact, it seems to be so basic but Google did not give me an answers. I have downloaded `ELKI`, this gave me a `.jar` file.

Now where do I put that archive/what do I do with it to be then able to use ELKI functions in my code?

I know this has to be really basic...but google does not help me there as everyone seems already to know.

Comment: Are you using an IDE such as Eclipse?

Comment: Also, consider using Maven. Totally works for me, saves hell of a time on resolving arcane amounts of tangled depedencies...

Comment: [Eclipse](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) [netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans)

Comment: I am using netbeans, and Maven to. That still does not help me with the question: where do I put the jar, what buttons do I have to press in netbeans/maven. Look, I have this problem quite often. The thing is, noone ever thought me how to include external libraries and I do not seem to be exactly apt at finding out myself.

Comment: update: I managed to add a dependancy and apparently I am now to run mvn install. I have, however, no Idea where to type this command?

Answer (score 0):

It's a .jar. You use it *exactly* like other jars, by adding them to your **Classpath**.

Command line Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Eclipse: [How to put a jar in classpath in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463354/how-to-put-a-jar-in-classpath-in-eclipse)

Netbeans: [How to add a JAR in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans)

Running maven commands: use a command prompt. This is basic operating system usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add dependency in gradle or maven without using jar

in gradle add in dependencies section:

```
 // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki/elki
compile group: 'de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki', name: 'elki', version: '0.7.1'
```

if you use maven add

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki/elki -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki</groupId>
    <artifactId>elki</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```