# (item) is not on the projects build path

Tags: java

[image: as far as I can see, both craftbukkit and UHC are on the buildpath][image]I decompiled a jar, imported the files into eclipse, and edited a few key java files. Whenever i try to export however, it gives me a

```
"JAR creation failed. See details for additional information. UHC-2.4.1/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF was replaced by the generated MANIFEST.MF and is no longer in the JAR. uk/co/eluinhost/UltraHardcore/features/core [in UHC-2.4.1] is not on its project's build path Unable to get package fragment root: UHC-2.4.1/uk/co/eluinhost/UltraHardcore/features/core/GoldenHeads.java uk/co/eluinhost/UltraHardcore/features/core [in UHC-2.4.1] is not on its project's build path" error.
```

I have searched far and wide for a solution, but have nor found one. I have tried refreshing the project etc, and all the necessary libraries are specified. Please help? Additional information: If I edit any other class (just add a space then delete it and then save) that class gets added to the error message as well.

Comment: This is probably not an issue with jar creation but compilation: source has to be compiled before being jarred. Are there any red X's in package explorer or the error view?

Comment: there are no red x's, look at the picture

Comment: Right you are user, I thought that was Navigator view for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. It looks like you have the MANIFEST.MF file (UHC-2.4.1/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF ) so just 
   when you are  exporting the jar file select the option for existing  manifest file and point it to UHC-2.4.1/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF .
2. You are missing a jar file (download the UHC-2.4.1.jar from [here](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/ultra-hardcore/files/13-ultra-hardcore-v2-4-1/) and and add it to class path.

I know you wrote that you have all the "necessary libraries" but make sure you have added them to your class path.

[image]

Comment: the meta-inf file being replaced was merely a warning, not an actual  error. It still gives me "JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
  uk/co/eluinhost/UltraHardcore/features/core [in UHC] is not on its project's build path
  Unable to get package fragment root: UHC/uk/co/eluinhost/UltraHardcore/features/core/GoldenHeads.java
uk/co/eluinhost/UltraHardcore/features/core [in UHC] is not on its project's build path"

Comment: @user2577576 I updated the answer for you. Hope it helps you.

Comment: please pardon the stupid question, but how can you go about adding something to the class path?

Comment: @user2577576 take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463354/how-to-put-a-jar-in-classpath-in-eclipse

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue.  I noticed that all of the files that were listed as "not on the project's build path" were open for editing in Eclipse.  Once I closed all of the open files, I was able to export the jar.

I assume they are locked for editing and so not exportable.

Comment: Thanks. Just closed all open java files in eclipse and the error was solved!

Answer (score 0):

Import the project from the parent folder, that's what fixed it for me.
In case you haven't noticed, they are not packages in your eclipse picture, that's one reason