# How to add Google JSON library into Eclipse?

Tags: json, eclipse, gson

I downloaded google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip and tried to add it to Eclipse (Kepler or Juno) project (Java Project or DynamicWeb - no matter)..

but all options:

```
- adding jar or zip to buildpath (under /lib dir, external Jars or local, not extacted)

- checking Order&Export and clean build 

 - Java7 and Java6..
```

No way..(I do not use maven and I am not planning so far)

It' ridiculous...

These libs work straight away in the same project:

```
          org.apache.sling.commons.json-2.0.6.jar
          json-simple-1.1.1.jar
```

Comment: It is the first thing I did

Comment: Sorry. Have you looked at my solution to set it into project class-path?

Comment: What the problem are you getting? Are you getting `ClassNotFoundException` in your project?

Comment: What the size of jar? Please confirm that is is not a corrupted jar. Its size should be around 186 KB.

Comment: see my answer below, please)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look.

- [Classpath in Eclipse](http://oopbook.com/java-classpath-2/classpath-in-eclipse/)
- [How to Add JARs to Project Build Paths in Eclipse (Java)](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)
- [FAQ How do I add an extra library to my project's classpath?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F)
- [How to put a jar in classpath in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463354/how-to-put-a-jar-in-classpath-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Oh my God...

in Google JSON library we have

```
            **JsonObject**
```

But in all other JSON libraries like

```
         org.apache.sling.commons.json-2.0.6.jar
         json-simple-1.1.1.jar
         wink-something-json.jar
```

We have

```
           **JSONObject**
```

So I could not found JSONObject or JSONArray in Google library..

Comment: You haven't mentioned such type of compilation errors to us otherwise you will get an answer within seconds.

Comment: Yes, my fault..I thought it's standard name

Comment: Not at all. Please can you tell how did you find it. From where you got a hint?

Comment: I just went inside JAR file and check classes' names)