# Which jar is missing?

Tags: eclipse, windows, hadoop, package, buildpath

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:169)
    at com.inspire.vote.VoteCountApplication.main(VoteCountApplication.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

I tried the code from this URL: https://github.com/hortonworks/hadoop-tutorials/blob/master/Community/T09_Write_And_Run_Your_Own_MapReduce_Java_Program_Poll_Result_Analysis.md

Comment: I suggest to add all jars in hadoop share folder to make it run, but this error seems to be due to unavailabily of logging or log4j jars.

Answer (score 1):

You must insert in your classpath the file org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar

Comment: I'm beginner How to do ?

Comment: You can download this file on this site: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonslogging111jar.htm

Then, you can follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463354/how-to-put-a-jar-in-classpath-in-eclipse

Comment: Added above via class lib. Project Folder shows no error. Yet can't RUN!