# How can i use jfxtras window in eclipse luna (efxclipse)

Tags: javafx, jinternalframe, jfxtras

There is no tutorial about to use jfxtras on eclipse. Or always maven and gradle installations. Please help

Comment: I do not understand the problem. You can use jfxtras via a Maven dependency, given that Maven is correctly setup in Eclipse. Or include it manually in the classpath.

Comment: @tbeernot how can i include manually?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a JFXtras related problem, you just need to learn how to use Eclipse. A google search will help with that. [How to put a jar in classpath in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463354/how-to-put-a-jar-in-classpath-in-eclipse)

In your eclipse project right click on the project name, in the popup menu select "build path", in de sub menu select "configure". In the window that opens, on the libraries tab, click the "Add external JAR" button and in the file chooser select all jfxtras jars you need.