# Java Eclipse showing error

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

[Out issue picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYGl6.png)[image: Picture 2]

Hi, Issue in the first picture has been resolved however, there is another issue occuring when I type out.println statement. 
Attaching picture 2 for reference.

Comment: did you import the necessary classes?

Comment: There is an `x` on an `import` statement, but Eclipse doesn't show all the imports unless you tell it to.  Please open up the `import` (click on the `+` sign) and tell us about the `import` statement that Eclipse doesn't like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `javax.servlet` jar in your project. [Download it](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1).

Add this jar in your `build path` and you will be good.

### See Also

- [How to put a jar in classpath in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463354/how-to-put-a-jar-in-classpath-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1 and download the `servlet` jar that you need in order to allow your code to access the necessary repositories. 
Next up, add this `.jar` file to your project's `classpath` by `Right click on project`->`build path`->`configure build path`->switch to the `libraries` tab->`add external jars` and browse to the location where you downloaded the necessary `.jar` file. 
Further, go ahead and make a `maven update` on your project, if it is a `maven` project, or if not, then simply `refresh` your project. That should solve your issue.