# Inheritence conflict between java ant projects

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have two Java projects, built with ANT, named Project A and B which I created in Luna Eclipse (the Java EE version). The package structure is as follows:

```
Project A
 |
 src
   |
   SomePackage
      |
      A.java
Project B
 |
 src
   |
   AnotherPackage
   |      |
   |      B.java
   |
   SomeOtherPackageInSrc
       |
       C.java
```

where A, B, and C are non-abstract POJOs. I also have the following inheritence structure:
C extends B, B extends A.
I added a public method to A, so that its children could have it. I then built project A, and added the resulting JAR to the project B's Build Path. I noticed that C could not access the new method. I then attached the source JAR to the build path, viewed the the source for A.java, and the newly added method was present. I tried a number of things, and adding project A to the [Deployment Assembly](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.2.0/NewAndNoteworthy/javaee.php) of project B allowed C to see the new method from A. Why does simply extending the class and adding the jar in which the extended class lives not provide visibility to public methods in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, only extending and adding the project to your classpath will make it compile, but it is not automatically in the resulting deployment unit (EAR/WAR). ANd this makes the classes unavailable at runtime.

Comment: That's the thing. C.java doesn't compile when I reference the new method added in A.java. I see no compile errors in Eclipse, but when I build with ANT, the call to the new method doesn't compile, failing with a cannot find symbol error. Following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463354/how-to-put-a-jar-in-classpath-in-eclipse) suggestion, I looked at the Java Build Path tab in Eclipse, and made sure the JAR from Project A was selected under Order and Export. The source.jar for Project A shows the new method, so I would think that means it's included in A.jar as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had multiple versions of the Project A JAR on my classpath, and the compiler picked up the old JAR instead of the new one. Rookie mistake.