# Adding JFXtras to my project

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jfxtras

Today when I searching on the Internet I found the JFXtras lib which contain awesome GUI component and other stuff but when I try to use it I can't?

I used other lib and add it like this way but JFXtras not!

I go to web site of project http://jfxtras.org/ and try to find jar file to add it to my project and use lib in project but I do not found it.

I am trying to figure out how to use this lib in my project.

Note:
I am using Eclipse mars

Comment: How did you tried to use it? What was the error or unexpected behavior? Describe your problem with more details.

Comment: if you don't use maven then you can find all libraries [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jfxtras/). after downloading required libraries you must add them your project's classpath

Comment: You can find the jars via the links in the "Use It" section on jfxtras.org. It refers directly to their snapshot and release Maven repositories (saves me from having to upload them manually). The all version contains all classes, if you do not use maven, that is the easiest.

Comment: smefju , I go to web page of JFXtras and try to find the jar file and add it to class path but i did not find the jar file.

Comment: If someone can show me how to add it to project and give me example , i will be thankful to him , pleas help me if you can !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with JFXtras, but with Eclipse and Java. Download [this](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jfxtras/jfxtras-labs/8.0-r6-SNAPSHOT/jfxtras-labs-8.0-r6-20160813.080203-78-all.jar) jar, and then follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463354/how-to-put-a-jar-in-classpath-in-eclipse) instruction

Comment: i will try it know to add jar file then to class lib of project , but until this could you tell me where can i get the jar file , because after that if there are update later.

Comment: it's work fine but when i add this to scene builder the component is not leaded fine !!

Comment: These are snapshot releases, the latest is the jar with the highest date in the name. Every night a snapshot is build. Every now and then a snapshot is turned into a formal release. That is how releasing usually goes in Java projects.

Comment: You are not very clear in what is going wrong. You need to be more specific. Also it is best if you start a new question, since this one is answered.