# Error Using HWPFDocument

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have been trying to read a .doc and .docx file and assign the text in the file into a String variable in java but I keep having the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       The type org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
>       The type org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I have the following code to test the program

```
 import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

public class ReadDocFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = null;
        WordExtractor extractor = null;
        try
        {

            file = new File("c:\\test.doc");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fis);
            extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
            String[] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();
            for (int i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++)
            {
                if (fileData[i] != null)
                    System.out.println(fileData[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exep)
        {
            exep.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have downloaded a .jar file from

> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad/3.9

I think the .jar file that I imported is incomplete. If so, can anyone give me a link for the complete library?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include **poi-3.15.jar** into your classpath.

You can find **all** poi jars & dependencies as **single** download [here](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.15-20160924.zip)

If you are using **maven**,

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi 
Sundararaj Govindasamy,

Comment: I downloaded the poi-3.15 folder but there is no .jar file there so I don't really know what to do. Sorry I'm a noob with this stuff. How do I import the poi library to eclipse?

Comment: What happens if you click the download link from my answer? It will download a zip which contains everything.To add downloaded jar into eclipse you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11463590/1401019  You can upvote-accept this answer, if it helps

Comment: The downloaded .zip file doesnt contain any .jar file so I don't see how I can use that.

Comment: I had the same issue with org.apache.poi v. 3.15 and 4.1.0.
It works for me while importing last (for today) library version - 4.1.1
Rebuilding gradle project didn't work for me. 
Strange for me was that I tried to use the same library version mentioned in: http://cuonglv.com/2019/03/20/how-to-replace-text-in-word-file-using-apache-poi/ and I couldn't use the same class from mentioned v 3.15.
Try to import 4.1.1.