# Connect to a database using the default URL and drive?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to connect to a database using `Java`. I use this code:

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    try {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "mysql";
        Class.forName(driver); 
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        return conn;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I don't know the correct default `url` and `driver` property values. I use `MySQLWorkBench`.

Comment: clarify what you want to know. currently you are missing the database name in the url

Comment: I have  a database called "DB1", with username "root", password "mysql", Network address: 127.0.0.1 and port 3306 and I want to make a connection

Comment: url: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB1`

Comment: i get: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB1?useSSL=false"

Comment: connector included in classpath?

Comment: import java.sql.Connection;    and    import java.sql.DriverManager; are imported using this jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar

Comment: no that is **not** what you need. you have to download [this file](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=470333) and [include it in your classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463354/how-to-put-a-jar-in-classpath-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

the Driver you are using is correct but you will need to download include mysql connector jar in your build path.

For the url the mysql is by default running on port 3306 so your url will be like this, replace [yourdatabasename] with the name of your database, useSSL is set since the connection is not https

```
     jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/[yourDatabasename]?useSSL=false
```

Comment: mysql connector in included, i changed my url with yours, now my url is "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB1?useSSL=false" but I get this error: "No suitable driver found for  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB1?useSSL=false"

Answer (score 0):

Your driver is `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` and your url will be `Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://{hostname}:3306/{schemaname}","{username}","password");`
and you can download the mysql jdbc driver from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html)

Hoping you would find this useful. Also remember 3306 is the default port and your MySQL instance should be running on this port. All the best :-)