# How to Install Fastutil using the .jar Executable file

Tags: java, fastutil

I'm trying to install fastutil-8.2.2 library on my pc, however the .jar far I download does not execute. The downloaded file is of type executable jar. I have Java SE Runtime environment installed as well. How do I install this? If installation is not possible, then how do I use these libraries after extraction of the file?

I have tried directly opening it, as well using

```
java -jar fastutil-8.2.2.jar
```

which gives me the output

```
no main manifest attribute, in fastutil-8.2.2.jar
```

the META-INF\MANIFEST file which I can see on extraction also does not contain any one-liner beginning with main-package.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are in wrong way.

I think fastutil DO NOT NEED INSTALL.

You just add fastutil-8.2.2.jar to your project library reference path, then will be fine.

What's your IDE?

Eclipse:  [how to add jar in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11463590/11226492)

Intellij Idea [the way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32853178/11226492)

Or using maven.